# How to throw exception in Angular Service Constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Service (A) that do some checks in its constructor and if something goes wrong throws an Exception. But the exception is not logged or catched by Angular. Is there a way to tell to Angular to stop because there is a critical error?

My service is inside a library module that I load in my main app. I tried to throw an error inside a Component constructor and it works. The service (A) instead ignore the exception and when it (A) is requested in other components/services constructors it is undefined.

Any IDEA? Do I have to implement a APP_INITIALIZER to execute the code inside the service (A) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea to throw exceptions inside a constructor. I would create a method inside the service to do some checks and call it when your application is building.

Comment: Yeah I think the same. I have't implemented this solution yet since the check is really simple. My service simply check if the environment contains a BASE_URL for my API.

Comment: Hmm, you can set a variable inside the service that marks the service as invalid due to some checks. Then you need to check this variable before using the service. It is clear that if a constructor throws an exception dependency injection is going to have a problem initialising the components and therefore the service is undefined..